# Changing from d3v4 to d3v3 makes the bars disappear

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following D3 code which works fine on d3v4, but due to conflict issues with another chart, we have to do it on d3v3. When I changed the library link from `https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js` to `https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js`, the bars disappear and only the text remain.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
text{
    font-size:12px;
}
.mainBars rect{
  shape-rendering: auto;
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  stroke-opacity: 0;
}
.subBars{
    shape-rendering:crispEdges;
}
.edges{
    stroke:none;
    fill-opacity:0.5;
}
.header{
    text-anchor:middle;
    font-size:16px;
}
line{
    stroke:grey;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vizjs.org/viz.v1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

var data=[['Lite','CA',16,0],
['Small','CA',1278,4],
['Medium','CA',27,0],
['Plus','CA',58,0],
['Grand','CA',1551,15],
['Elite','CA',141,0],
['Lite','AZ',5453,35],
['Small','AZ',683,1],
['Medium','AZ',862,0],
['Grand','AZ',6228,30],
['Lite','AL',15001,449],
['Small','AL',527,3],
['Medium','AL',836,0],
['Plus','AL',28648,1419],
['Grand','AL',3,0],
['Lite','CO',13,0],
['Small','CO',396,0],
['Medium','CO',362,0],
['Plus','CO',78,10],
['Grand','CO',2473,32],
['Elite','CO',2063,64],
['Medium','DE',203,0],
['Grand','DE',686,2],
['Elite','DE',826,0],
['Lite','KS',1738,110],
['Small','KS',12925,13],
['Medium','KS',15413,0],
['Small','GA',2166,2],
['Medium','GA',86,0],
['Plus','GA',348,3],
['Grand','GA',4244,18],
['Elite','GA',1536,1],
['Small','IA',351,0],
['Grand','IA',405,1],
['Small','IL',914,1],
['Medium','IL',127,0],
['Grand','IL',1470,7],
['Elite','IL',516,1],
['Lite','IN',43,0],
['Small','IN',667,1],
['Medium','IN',172,0],
['Plus','IN',149,1],
['Grand','IN',1380,5],
['Elite','IN',791,23],
['Small','FL',1,0],
['Grand','FL',1,0],
['Small','MD',1070,1],
['Grand','MD',1171,2],
['Elite','MD',33,0],
['Plus','TX',1,0],
['Small','MS',407,0],
['Medium','MS',3,0],
['Grand','MS',457,2],
['Elite','MS',20,0],
['Small','NC',557,0],
['Medium','NC',167,0],
['Plus','NC',95,1],
['Grand','NC',1090,5],
['Elite','NC',676,6],
['Lite','NM',1195,99],
['Small','NM',350,3],
['Medium','NM',212,0],
['Grand','NM',1509,8],
['Lite','NV',3899,389],
['Small','NV',147,0],
['Medium','NV',455,0],
['Plus','NV',1,1],
['Grand','NV',4100,16],
['Lite','OH',12,0],
['Small','OH',634,2],
['Medium','OH',749,0],
['Plus','OH',119,1],
['Grand','OH',3705,19],
['Elite','OH',3456,25],
['Small','PA',828,2],
['Medium','PA',288,0],
['Plus','PA',141,0],
['Grand','PA',2625,7],
['Elite','PA',1920,10],
['Small','SC',1146,2],
['Medium','SC',212,0],
['Plus','SC',223,4],
['Grand','SC',1803,6],
['Elite','SC',761,8],
['Small','TN',527,0],
['Medium','TN',90,0],
['Grand','TN',930,4],
['Elite','TN',395,1],
['Lite','ME',7232,58],
['Small','ME',1272,0],
['Medium','ME',1896,0],
['Plus','ME',1,0],
['Grand','ME',10782,33],
['Elite','ME',1911,3],
['Small','VA',495,0],
['Medium','VA',32,0],
['Plus','VA',7,0],
['Grand','VA',1557,12],
['Elite','VA',24,0],
['Small','WA',460,1],
['Plus','WA',88,3],
['Grand','WA',956,3],
['Small','WV',232,0],
['Medium','WV',71,0],
['Grand','WV',575,2],
['Elite','WV',368,3]
];
var color ={Elite:"#3366CC", Grand:"#DC3912",  Lite:"#FF9900", Medium:"#109618", Plus:"#990099", Small:"#0099C6"};
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 960).attr("height", 800);

svg.append("text").attr("x",250).attr("y",70)
    .attr("class","header").text("Sales Attempt");

svg.append("text").attr("x",750).attr("y",70)
    .attr("class","header").text("Sales");

var g =[svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(150,100)")
        ,svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(650,100)")];

var bp=[ viz.bP()
        .data(data)
        .min(12)
        .pad(1)
        .height(600)
        .width(200)
        .barSize(35)
        .fill(d=>color[d.primary])
    ,viz.bP()
        .data(data)
        .value(d=>d[3])
        .min(12)
        .pad(1)
        .height(600)
        .width(200)
        .barSize(35)
        .fill(d=>color[d.primary])
];

[0,1].forEach(function(i){
    g[i].call(bp[i])

    g[i].append("text").attr("x",-50).attr("y",-8).style("text-anchor","middle").text("Channel");
    g[i].append("text").attr("x", 250).attr("y",-8).style("text-anchor","middle").text("State");

    g[i].append("line").attr("x1",-100).attr("x2",0);
    g[i].append("line").attr("x1",200).attr("x2",300);

    g[i].append("line").attr("y1",610).attr("y2",610).attr("x1",-100).attr("x2",0);
    g[i].append("line").attr("y1",610).attr("y2",610).attr("x1",200).attr("x2",300);

    g[i].selectAll(".mainBars")
        .on("mouseover",mouseover)
        .on("mouseout",mouseout);

    g[i].selectAll(".mainBars").append("text").attr("class","label")
        .attr("x",d=>(d.part=="primary"? -30: 30))
        .attr("y",d=>+6)
        .text(d=>d.key)
        .attr("text-anchor",d=>(d.part=="primary"? "end": "start"));

    g[i].selectAll(".mainBars").append("text").attr("class","perc")
        .attr("x",d=>(d.part=="primary"? -100: 80))
        .attr("y",d=>+6)
        .text(function(d){ return d3.format("0.0%")(d.percent)})
        .attr("text-anchor",d=>(d.part=="primary"? "end": "start"));
});

function mouseover(d){
    [0,1].forEach(function(i){
        bp[i].mouseover(d);

        g[i].selectAll(".mainBars").select(".perc")
        .text(function(d){ return d3.format("0.0%")(d.percent)});
    });
}
function mouseout(d){
    [0,1].forEach(function(i){
        bp[i].mouseout(d);

        g[i].selectAll(".mainBars").select(".perc")
        .text(function(d){ return d3.format("0.0%")(d.percent)});
    });
}
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

A working example with d3v4 can be seen [here](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/cd80ab54c52f80c4d84cad0ba9da72c2).Is there something I am missing out on? Should we also change the viz.js library version? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct you will need to downgrade the viz minor version from:

http://vizjs.org/viz.v1.1.0.min.js

to

http://vizjs.org/viz.v1.0.0.min.js